# How to initialize a point array in declaration java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I was wondering on how to initialize a point array when you declare it.
I was thinking it would be similar to

```
int[] num = {4,7,8};
```

But I realized that points have x and y values so how would you do the above for point arrays?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider doing something like:

```
Point[] myPoints = {
  new Point(1, 2),
  new Point(3, 4)
}
```

This is a specific case of the general reference array.

```
MyType[] myTypeArray = {
   new MyType(...),
   new MyType(...),
   // .... etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean, something like

```
int[][] num = new int[][] {
    new int[] {1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {4, 5, 6},
    new int[] {7, 8, 9},
};

int x = 1, y = 0;

System.out.println( num[y][x] );  // -> 2
```

?

Comment: similar but it was for points not int, i got it ow thanks to another user but thanks for your help

Comment: Either way, but using `Point` is definitly better, of course!